# Передача параметра даты при вызове хранимой процедуры MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Вызываю хранимую процедуру с параметром типа datetime из проекта ADP Access 2003, выдаёт ошибку

> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции '-'

Пробовал разные форматы дат, но ошибка однотипная повторяется, только конструкции другие.

Вызов из кода

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & "," & DueDate
```

Хранимая процедура

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_pct_ItemForTree]
     @group_id int=21
    ,@instoreonly int=1
    ,@idbrand int=-1
    ,@hotim bit=1
    ,@fltr varchar(150)=''
    ,@inet bit = 0
    ,@idbill int=null
    ,@dueDate datetime = null
```

Пример даты

```
2015-09-22
```

Строка, после конкатенации

```
"exec usp_pct_ItemForTree 0,6,-1,1,'',0,5425157,2015-09-22"
```

Comment: Приведите хотя бы пример, что за значение в DueDate лежит. А еще лучше пример того, какая строка на выходе получается после конкатенации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в настройках locale.
На клиенте и сервере установлены разные locale. Клиент передает дату в одних региональных настройках, в то время когда сервер ожидает принять в других.

Отсюда и возникает ошибка преобразования строки `varchar` к `datetime`. Нужно смотреть настройки сервера. В каком формате от принимает параметры типа `datetime`. Или использовать инструкцию [set dateformat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) перед выполнением обновления в хранимой процедуре.

Ну и обязательно использование одинарных кавычек, как правильно заметил Aries. Без этого никуда. Дату следует передавать в хп так же как и строковые параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & ",'" & DueDate & "'"
```

Comment: Ошибка преобразования типа данных `varchar` к `datetime`

Comment: @Anatol, у меня сейчас нет под рукой Access, поэтому могу только гадать. Но такой формат `22/09/2015` не пробовали? И плюс обратить внимание, что в целом не является хорошей практикой использовать datetime для даты, если Вам не надо хранить время. Есть же просто тип date.